# Python 3 pip installation of pygraphviz fails, "Microsoft Visual C++ is required", Visual Studio 2017 is installed

Tags: c++, visual-studio, python-3.6, pygraphviz

I tried to `pip install pygraphviz`, which failed with the error:

`"Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. ..."`

I have Visual Studio 2017 installed. Shouldn't that do the job? I think I checked every box related to C.

If I try to install vc_redist.x64.exe, it tells me another version is already installed.

(I think I have a similar/related problem with SciKit-learn and Scipy.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From PyGraphviz documentation -

> To use PyGraphviz you need Python version 2.6.x or 2.7.x. PyGraphviz
>   does not work with Python 3.

[link](https://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/pygraphviz-1.3rc1/install.html) to more info.

Comment: No longer true. I have gotten it to work with python3.

Comment: @darkhipo you don't need to downvote for that. A comment would do. This answer was relevant at the time it was written.

Comment: @darkhipo Thank you. I'll try it out. For now I have found a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2017 comes with version 15 of the C++ compiler.  It's quite possible that pygraphviz truly wants version 14 (rather than 14-or-better).  Version 14 came with VS 2015.

Microsoft's C++ compiler routinely breaks the ABI of the standard library between major versions.  They may stop doing that in the future, but that doesn't help you with this problem.  You need to get your hands on VC++ 14 (or at least the [redistributables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299.aspx) that came with VC++14).